# Can't issue identities on fabric bluemix instance for fabric composer business network

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I launched a hyperledger fabric starter instance on IBM Bluemix.
I deployed a fabric composer business network to it. I can create assets, participants and transactions using the auto-created admin credentials. So far so good. What doesn't work though is issuing an identity for a participant. I get the below error:

```
$ composer identity issue -n businessNetwork -p bluemixProfile -i admin -s 39631b62329d0 -u paul -a "org.notarynodes.businessNetwork.Person#paul"

2017-03-31T16:34:46.933Z ERROR   HFCUtil                 
:createIdentity()
Register request failed
{"0":{"stack":["{Error}Invalid affiliation group institution_a Error:
Invalid affiliation group institution_a"," at
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:417:17"]}}$
Error: Invalid affiliation group institution_a Command failed.
```

How can I solve that error?

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a way to provide the affiliation name on the identity issue command. I have created a github issue
https://github.com/fabric-composer/fabric-composer/issues/606
about this.